# Adding button with Ajax callback in node using preprocess_node

Tags: theming, ajax

I have my_theme and my_project. Also have a file called `my_project.php`. There I have two functions and in both of them I have ALMOST the same structure:

```
function my_theme_preprocess_node__foo(&$variables){
  $variables['bye'] = [
    '#type' => 'button',
    '#value' => 'Value',
    '#description' => 'Description', 
    '#ajax' => [
      'callback' => 'Drupal\my_project\MyProjectAjax::queryTestVisual', 
      'event' => 'click',
      'progress' => [
        'type' => 'throbber',
        'message' => t('Wait...'),
      ],
    ],
    '#attached' => [
      'library' => [
        'my_theme/my-project-visual',
      ]
    ]
  ];
}


function my_theme_form_node_foo_form_alter(&$form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state){
  $form['hi'] = [
    '#type' => 'button',
    '#value' => 'Value',
    '#description' => 'Description', 
    '#ajax' => [
      'callback' => 'Drupal\my_project\MyProjectAjax::queryTestForm', 
      'event' => 'click',
      'progress' => [
        'type' => 'throbber',
        'message' => t('Wait...'),
      ],
    ],
    '#attached' => [
      'library' => [
        'my_theme/my-project-form',
      ]
    ]
  ];
}
```

Then I call buttons like:

In `myvisual.html.twig`:
`{{bye}}`

In `myform.html.twig`:
`{{form.hi}}`

I can see both buttons but only the form one (`{{form.hi}}`) does the callback.

Any idea why? Do I have to do write some extra code to make it work on preprocess_node?

Comment: You are mixing templating (`preprocess_node`, frontend rendering) with Form API (`form_alter`, backend data manipulation). Take a look at https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/elements/8.2.x to see which `[#type]` are only available in Form API. Also take a look at the general `[#type] => 'ajax'` Render Element

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So I can't use [#type] => 'ajax' without a form. Which method can I use from node? I'm pretty lost now.